# Injecting a property in MVC 3 with Ninject

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ninject

I'm trying to inject a property into an ActionFilter of mine called UnitOfWorkAttribute. I have this code:

```
[Inject]
public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }
```

Before that gets executed, I tell Ninject to resolve this with:

```
Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<NHibernateUnitOfWork>().InThreadScope();
```

My problem is that in my UnitOfWorkAttribute class, whenever I try to use my UnitOfWork property, It comes through as Null. This is my interface:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    void Begin();
    void Commit();
    void Rollback();
}
```

and this is my concrete:

```
public interface INHibernateUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    ISession Session { get; }
}

public class NHibernateUnitOfWork : INHibernateUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly ISessionSource sessionSource;
    private ITransaction transaction;
    private ISession session;

    private bool disposed;
    private bool begun;

    public NHibernateUnitOfWork(ISessionSource sessionSource)
    {
        this.sessionSource = sessionSource;
        Begin();
    }

    //.......
}
```

I am fulfilling the interface under the //......

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that Ninject never gets a chance to "do it's thing" on the ActionFilter, that's handled internally in MVC by the `FilterAttributeFilterProvider`. What you need to do is to tell MVC to use a custom `FilterAttributeFilterProvider` where you can intercept the filters before they are executed. Allow me to demonstrate:

Say I have this interface and implementation:

```
public interface IFoo
{

}

public class Foo : IFoo
{

}
```

Then I have an ActionFilter:

```
public class MyActionFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public MyActionFilterAttribute()
    {
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //do something with Foo
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }

    [Inject]
    public IFoo Foo { get; set; }
}
```

And then we have a controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [MyActionFilter]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

If you were to run this now as is, obviously Foo would still be null inside the MyActionFilter, so let's keep going....

Let's set up the Ninject DependencyResolver:

```
public class NinjectDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;

    public NinjectDependencyResolver(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _kernel.TryGet(serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return _kernel.GetAll(serviceType);
    }
}
```

Now let's use that in the Global.asax:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(GetKernel()));
    }

    private IKernel GetKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>();
        return kernel;
    }
```

Getting closer, but MVC still doesn't have a way to use the Ninject kernel when creating the Action Filters. Here's where we'll make that happen.

First:

```
public class NinjectFilterProvider : FilterAttributeFilterProvider
{
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;

    public NinjectFilterProvider(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    public override IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        var filters = base.GetFilters(controllerContext, actionDescriptor);

        foreach (var filter in filters)
        {

            _kernel.Inject(filter.Instance);
        }

        return filters;
    }
}
```

What's happening here is that we're creating a custom FilterAttributeFilterProvider class. In the OnActionExecuting method, right after we get all the filters through the base implementation,  we can call Ninjects Inject method which will inspect the instance and see if it can inject anything into it (using the Inject attribute).

The final piece of the puzzle is to set up the binding for our custom FilterAttributeFilterProvider:

Global.asax:

```
    private IKernel GetKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>();
        //use our custom NinjectFilterProvider
        kernel.Bind<IFilterProvider>().To<NinjectFilterProvider>();
        return kernel;
    }
```

Now, when MVC goes to get an `IFilterProvider` (it does so automatically through the DependencyResolver) it won't get the default `FilterAttributeFilterProvider` rather it'll get our custom `NinjectFilterProvider` and our Foo instance will thus be populated inside the custom Action Filter.

Comment: That's all nice, but largely unneeded.  Ninject.MVC provides a nice little feature called BindFilter, you can read about it here https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/wiki/Filter-configurations

Comment: @MystereMan There's only ever one way to do things?

Comment: No, but it's a bit like giving someone the recipe when all they want to know is where they can get some cookies.

Comment: @MystereMan Cute analogy :) Just because there's an open source project that does this, doesn't mean it isn't helpful to explain the actual approach. In fact, it seems that this is the exact approach ninject.web.mvc takes: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/blob/master/mvc3/src/Ninject.Web.Mvc/MvcModule.cs

Comment: I ended up using the extension BindFilter found in Ninject.MVC3.

Comment: @BFree - It's an actual official Ninject extension, maintained by Remo.  It's not like it's some vague 3rd party library.